# Facebook App in PHP

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm wanting to learn how to write facebook app with php, herez the codes:

```
<?php
        require_once('facebook/src/facebook.php');
        $appapikey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
        $appsecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
        $facebook = new Facebook($appapikey, $appsecret);
        $user=$facebook->getUser();

?>

<html>
        <head>
                <title>Test</title>
        </head>
        <body>
                <?php echo $user; ?>Test
        </body>
</html>
```

you can see the app here, https://apps.facebook.com/noorphp, I'm wanting to see `<userId>Test` but I'm seeing only `0Test`

So, I'm not getting the userid

Comment: I just try the url again, it works for me

Comment: maybe its not published for public only for admin now

Comment: @ Mohit Bumb, no, u right, there is a problem!!

Comment: @Mohit Bumb, is there any specific option i should set to make it public??

Comment: No i don't think any special option in app setting but yes check your app or your app page there's option

Comment: Do you think there is any problem with the codes??

Comment: no, its not coding problem i'm 100% sure, well it happens with me when i deactivate my account and again activate it then my old apps. stop working for others i check my app / app page i don't remember and activate it

Comment: @Mohit Bumb, now its ok, you can test it, my problem is that i'm not getting the userid with my current codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well still showing me 404 error please check if you've restriction for any country but for me this code works

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => $app_id,
        'secret' => $app_secret,
        'cookie' => true
));
$user=$facebook->getUser();
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you can get the user's ID, he needs to be connected with your App. Which means you have to ask him for permission to access his basic profile information (or additional permissions if required by your App).

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getUser/

Comment: Yes, normally, this is asked at the beginning, when you connect to the app for the first time, it ask you:

THIS APP WILL RECEIVE:
Your basic info
Your e-mail address (xxxx)

& when you agree and go to app, it normally get the right i think. Is that so??